# What is the difference between temp.next and temp?

Tags: linked-list

Please anyone clear my doubt this is realated to linked list

1. When we are traversing a linked list then we are writing inside a
   while (temp!=null){}
2. When we are inserting element at the end then we are writing inside the while (temp.next!=null){}

So please tell me exactly what is the difference between in these two cases

Answer (score 0):

Usually, pointers to the current node and the next one, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to visit each node then this loop is all you need:

```java
while (temp!=null){
    // Do the processing with this node
    // ...
    // Go to next
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

It becomes a different story when you need to find out which is the **tail** node. The above loop will end with `temp` being `null` and although the loop certainly visited the last node, we didn't keep a reference to it. If we wanted to have that reference still, we should have quit looping one iteration *earlier*.

And *that* is why we need a different loop condition -- to make sure we exit the loop when we still have the reference to the last node.

Usually such loop will be preceded by a separate check to see whether `temp` is null:

```java
if (temp == null) {
    // deal with this boundary case
    // ...
} else {
    while (temp.next!=null){
        // Usually there is no processing here. The purpose is only to find the tail
        // Go to next
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    // At this point temp is not null, but a reference to the tail node.
    // Here can follow some logic that attaches a new node after that tail node
    temp.next = new Node(newValue);
}
```

Comment: I understood the concept thanks for answering